# Check if a value exists in a database and return the value if it does Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I am running Rails here with a **User** model that contains an :email_address column

I have an array - **emails_to_check[email1,email2,email3]** that i want to check if they exist in the User database.

I only want to return the values that DO exist in the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple one-liner for you. There may be more performant ways, but this is maybe the most straight-forward and idiomatic Rails.

```
emails_to_check = ['email1', 'email2', 'email3']
User.where(email_address: emails_to_check).pluck(:email_address)
```

Here is the resulting SQL query:

```
SELECT `users`.`email_address` FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email_address` IN ('email1', 'email2', 'email3');
```

Answer (score 0):

so i solved this using a rake task

```
task :find_users_in_array,[:emails_to_find] => :environment do |task, args|
emails = args[:emails_to_find].split

emails.each do |email|
  if User.find_by(email:email)
      puts "#{email}"
  end
end
end
```

I can pass in a list using **rake:find_users_in_array[email1 email2 email3]**

Comment: Seems complicated. The one-liner @BenFenner proposes seems good.

Comment: yes the one-liner there is the solution I was looking for - but i guess this way i can pass the values into rails locally and get a result with the rake task this way as well

Comment: There's no reason you can't use alternative solutions in your rake task. Give it a try. :)